# Appropriate GLMM distribution for ratings data that are bounded and discrete

Tags: regression, distributions, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, glmm

I am using a linear mixed model to explain variation in an object's ratings. These ratings are bounded between 0 and <strike>10</strike> 9, and take only discrete values (example histogram of the raw data below). Note that the distance between values can be thought of as consistent across the scale (unlike in a typical Likert scale) i.e. the difference between 1 and 2 is about the same as that between 8 and 9.

I know that a normal distribution *can* be a useful enough approximation for discrete data in some cases, but I suspect that I need to use a generalized linear model for this.

What sort of distribution/link function would be appropriate for this type of data?

---

Edit: I should note that I am using a mixed model with random effects to account for non-independence due to multiple measurements by some individuals. My apologies for not including this detail earlier.

Edit 2: the bounds are not 0 and 10 as I stated above, but 0 and 9.

[image: Histogram of ratings]

Comment: I suggest binomial family and logit link. In software I know 10 would be specified as the upper limit.

Comment: What about a model that deals explicitly with the ordinal nature of the ratings such as a proportional odds model?

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for the comment. I'll look into how to specify the upper limit in R's glmm packages, it's not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thanks for chiming in. I did consider that, but in this data the intervals can be considered to be equally spaced (i.e. distance between 1 and 2 is essentially the same as between 8 and 9). For that reason, I thought that it did not need an ordinal regression approach.

Comment: @mkt Just because the ratings are equally spaced doesn't mean you can treat the rating as metric in my opinion (see [here](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2017/12/which-movie-is-rated-better-dont-treat.html) and [here](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2018/01/dont-treat-ordinal-data-as-metric.html)). Your comment gives me the impression that you want to avoid an ordinal model if possible and only use it when it is needed. Could you explain why you hope to use another model?

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thank you for those links, I will take a look. I'm open to switching, but you're right that I do have a mild bias towards avoiding ordinal models. This is simply because I'm less familiar with them and therefore less able to judge weaknesses/problems in model diagnostics. But if they are the best option here, I'll gladly use them.

Comment: It does seem odd that 9 is the mode while 10 doesn't occur at all.

Comment: @NickCox Agreed, that is a strange pattern. Possibly a cultural bias, because I'm familiar with other such cases where the highest value is viewed as unattainable perfection. Which now that I type that, I realise contradicts my claims of the intervals being equally spaced.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a linear model? A regression tree (or trees like RF) would probably do well too. If anything it will have no problem with predicting outside the range of available data. Also have you considered a Tobit model?

Comment: @usεr11852 Thanks, those are helpful thoughts. I agree that RFs could be valuable, but there is additional complexity to the models (random effects) that don't integrate well with them. I should have mentioned that in the question, my apologies. I'm unfamiliar with Tobit models, will look them up.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue in academic assessment in which teachers are allowed to give 100% but won't because supposedly no paper is perfect. This means that mathematicians are more likely to win prizes....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a crude representation with a reasonable mean-variance relationship, a quasibinomial model would probably work OK: in R,

```
glm(cbind(score,10-score) ~ ..., family=quasibinomial, ...)
```

`cbind(score,10-score)` specifies to treat the response as a number of "successes" out of a maximum 10. Specifically, this means you'd be fitting a model with a predicted value of

$$
\mu = \textrm{logistic}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + ...)
$$

where $x_i$ are your predictor variables and $\mu$ is the proportion out of 10. The assumed mean-variance relation is $V \propto \mu(1-\mu)$, which is reasonable since you expect the variance to decrease when the average score approaches 0 or the maximum value.

As pointed out in the comments, this does assume that the levels are in some sense "equally spaced" (although the logistic transformation does mean that it will take (for example) less difference in predictors to go from 4 to 5 or 5 to 6 than from 1 to 2 or from 9 to 10 ...)  An ordinal model would add an extra $n-1$ parameters to quantify the distances between levels.

Comment: Thanks very much, Ben! This makes sense to me. As an aside, would this be possible to implement in GLMMs? My understanding was that glmer & glmmTMB didn't allow quasi-families.

Comment: It appears to be implementable in glmmPQL, though I'm less familiar with that.

Comment: there's code in the GLMM FAQ that shows how to convert a summary table from (e.g.) binomial to quasibinomial by adjusting standard errors and p-values appropriately.

Answer (score 7):

You could also treat your outcome as an ordinal variable and fit a mixed-effects model for this ordinal response. Ordinal mixed models are available in the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package; for an example, check the vignette [Mixed Models for Ordinal Data](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Ordinal_Mixed_Models.html).

Alternatively, and if you do not have any missing data in your outcome (or the missing data that you may have can be assumed to be missing completely at random), you could also consider using generalized estimating equations (GEEs), either with a binomial family or an ordinal one. These are available in the [**geepack**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=geepack) in the functions `geeglm(..., family = binomial())` and `ordgee()`, respectively. The GEEs work under quasi-likelihood and include an over-dispersion parameter automatically.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for the suggestions! Much appreciated, I will look into those.